# Making a property in C# with Lambda expressions including a condition

Tags: c#, lambda, properties, try-catch, throw

I'm starting learning C# and I'm wondering how I could improve a property using Lambda Expressions.

I know how to use it for a "get" but not a "set".

### How I'm currently doing it:

```cs
public string Name
            {
                get => name;
                set
                {
                    if(value.Trim().Length >= 1) { name = value; }
                    else
                    {
                        characterCount--;
                        throw new Exception("Error : Character name is invalid");                        
                    }
                }
            }
```

The following answers will help me learn more about them !

Comment: You can wrap your validation into a method and use it like this `set => name = YourMethod()`

Comment: Tip: `x.Trim().Length` could involve allocations; if all you want to know is if there's some non-whitespace characters in there, consider `string.IsNullOrWhitespace(x)`

Answer (score 1):

Lambda expressions are intended to be exactly that: expressions; your code with multiple statements: isn't a single expression, so: don't try and squeeze it into a lambda. There's nothing wrong with the `{...}` approach - it is clear, readable, maintainable, etc. Leave it alone!

Note, you *could* torture a "switch expression" using a "when" to enforce your conditions to get the success case, and use the default (`_`) case if the switch expression to throw the exception, and assign the result of the switch expression to the field; it would technically be using a lambda for the set and maintaining your intent, but IMO it would reduce readability. So: don't do that!

Your goal should not be to write clever code - it should be to write clear and obvious code. Which you already have.

Note: I'm not making any comments on the `characterCount--;` - that sounds like a very bizarre side-effect, and is probably a bad thing to do.

But (completely untested, purely for illustration):

```cs
public string Name
{
    get => name;
    set => name = value switch {
        string s when !string.IsNullOrWhitespace(s) => s,
        _ => throw new Exception("Error : Character name is invalid"),
    }
}
```